# jQuery Cookie not being set when followed by redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, coldfusion

This is a very common question that has an even more common answer, problem is, is that it isn't working for me.

I'm using the jquery.cookie.js plugin, and as I noticed there was an ISS bug that hindered setting cookies and redirect at the same time I'll point out that I'm using a local WAMP server to build this.

I set a cookie variable and then redirect to another page as per the below code:

```
$.cookie("TEST", "Hola!", { 
    expires: 1,
    path: '/'          
});

if ($.cookie("TEST")) {
    window.location.href = "./test.cfm";
}
```

However, as soon as I attempt to redirect the cookie is not set. When I remove the redirect the cookie is set. I've tried multiple variations on this theme, I've set up an ajax call to the server and set the cookie there which has the same effect. I've used different methods of redirecting the page to the same effect as well.

My issue seems to stem from including both the setting of the cookie and the redirect together.

Extra info I'm using Firebug to see if cookies are being set or not and to be sure I've set up on the redirect page (in ColdFusion):

```
<CFOUTPUT>
    #cookie.TEST#<br />
    Como Estas?
</CFOUTPUT>
```

This returns -99.

All ideas are greatly welcomed.

Comment: Is the redirect to a different domain or sub-domain?

Comment: Nope, it is as you see above a relative link to another file in the same folder.

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers or just Firefox?

Comment: I've recreated this now in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: Try specifying the entire path in your redirect line. Like this `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/test.cfm";`

Comment: Yep, I've tried this as well to no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid that I am out of suggestions. Perhaps you would be better off posting your question to whichever javascript plugin that you are using for the cookie handling. You don't seem to be getting a lot of responses here.

Comment: In the end I worked around the issue without using cookies. So I'll just leave the question up to hopefully be answered one day by an interested passerby. Until then thanks for the idea of posting it to the jQuery cookie plugin group. I'll give that a go.